# Is a journal article published as a third author and a dissertation for an undergraduate student good enough for funding for master's studies as RA?

Tags: research-undergraduate, research-assistantship

I am an undergraduate about to graduate within the next six months. I have a research article as a third author in a journal with an impact factor of 3+ related to machine learning used for Bioinformatics. I have another manuscript that may not get published, since my supervisor suddenly made me compete with a labmate for the same datasets. After showing him the results of my work, his work got published since his results were better than mine, although I had defeated previous research works on 3 out of 5 of the mentioned datasets without my name in the authorship or acknowledgement list. I felt that it was wrong of my supervisor to make me show a labmate the results of my research and make me compete with him for a publication. Correct me if I am wrong.

But now, I want to apply abroad for research assistantships for my master's in machine learning-related studies right after graduation because I'm not financially stable. My question is if my profile is good enough to start applying for funding as an RA. I have one publication as a third author in a journal and an unpublished work as a first author which I will use for undergraduate thesis dissertation. Or should I try to publish another research article before applying? How should I state my unpublished works in my CV?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, your record is impressive for an undergraduate, and as far as I can tell few people can match it when starting their Masters' work - which is when one usually first conducts publishable research.

But note that many places don't offer funded Masters' work, regardless of your achievements, or may prioritize graduates of the same institution etc.

Finally, I believe you should not completely slant your choice of institution based on funding. I realize that your financial situation is a constraint, but - diverting years of your life to working and studying some subject, and in some environment, which is not where you'd like to be is a very high price to pay.

Comment: The second paragraph warning is especially important here. In US, almost all RAs are for doctoral study.

Answer (score 1):

IMO that is great!

I got into graduate school having done a thesis and being a much later author on a paper, but really it is going to depend on what funding is available/who else is applying when you apply to graduate school. Though I do not see why you would not be able to apply and hopefully have some luck.

Also if you create a section in your CV called publications you can mark some as "In progress:" *Insert citation info here*